# rgl.postscript exporting zero-length files

Tags: r, rgl

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to export a postscript or pdf snapshot of a `persp3d` plot using `rgl.postscript`. I've added code from `?rgl.postscript` which works for me without error in R but produces a 0 KB postscript file. Any ideas?

```
x <- y <- seq(-10,10,length=20)
z <- outer(x,y,function(x,y) x^2 + y^2)
persp3d(x,y,z, col='lightblue')

title3d("Using LaTeX text", col='red', line=3)
rgl.postscript("persp3da.ps","ps",drawText=FALSE)
```

FYI, I'm running R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10), Windows 8 (64-bit), rgl package 0.94.1143

Comment: Can't reproduce. This code works for me, but I am in OSX. In OSX I need to have X11 installed. Maybe the Windows version has similar requirements?

Comment: After second thought- I assumed title3d() produces the desired output. Does it?

Comment: Yup, everything - including title3d - prints as expected in R...but for some reason rgl.postscript doesn't put anything into the postscript or pdf

Comment: Just a silly comment in case... rgl.postscript() created a A4 ps file with the image at the bottom. When I opened at first thought it was empty until I realized and scrolled down the page. There is no way that is what's happening?

Comment: A more serious comment, I imagine rgl.postscript() uses ghostscript or something alike to create the postscript file. Could it be that you need to install it?

Comment: Good thinking! I have ghostscript installed but I didn't make sure R could find it. Alas, after specifying the path to ghostscript using Sys.setenv(), I still get nothing :(

Comment: Have you tried using a different format, with rgl.postscript(<filename>, fmt="pdf") or something else? See ?rgl.postscript for format options. Otherwise I am currently out of ideas! Unfortunately do not have a windows machine to test.

Comment: Yup, gave all the options a try (I should have clarified that in the question). Many thanks for sharing your ideas!